# How to make a array smaller and move every value one place down

Tags: c#, arrays

Here is the array

```
                string[] Numbers = new string[5] { "1", "2", "", "3", "4" };
```

As you can see I have 1 item that has nothing in it.
What I'm trying to do is make the array smaller and move, everything after the clear space, 1 down. I'm also going to use it for a bigger array. But it will always have just 1 clear space.

```
{"1", "2", "3", "4"}
```

This is what I'm trying to get.

Here are the variables

```
int intSelected, intCounter = 1, intAmount = Numbers.length;
```

And here is the code

```
        while (true)
        {
            Numbers[intSelected + intCounter] = Numbers[intSelected + intCounter - 1];

            if (intSelected + intCounter == intAmount)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref Numbers, Numbers.Length - 1);
                MessageBox.Show("It works");
                intAmount--;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                intCounter++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're going to be creating a new array anyway (rather than leave it at its original size while copying elements), why not just `Numbers = Numbers.Where(n => n != "").ToArray()`?

Comment: If you can use Memory/Span instead of Array, you can simply use `.Slice (1)`

Answer (score 4):

One of the simplest ways to do it is to use `System.Linq` to filter the undesired items out:

```
string[] Numbers = new string[5] { "1", "2", "", "3", "4" };
string[] ClearNumbers = Numbers.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e)).ToArray();
```

Comment: What value does 'e' need to have?

Comment: @Tomaatje07 the `e` is comparable to the var within a foreach loop: its the current element during iteration. So, first e is "1", then "2", then "" which gets thrown out by the where clause, and so on

Comment: `e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e)` is a lambda expression here, a function that takes items from the collection one by one. can be presented as `bool MyFunction(string e) { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e); } }`

Answer (score 2):

No Linq solution (you've used `Array.Resize` in your code; let's correct it). We scan the array, copy items on empty spaces and, finally, resize the array:

```
string[] Numbers = new string[5] { "1", "2", "", "3", "4" };

...

int lastIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.Length; ++i)
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Numbers[i])) // if Numbers[i] should be preserved...
    Numbers[lastIndex++] = Numbers[i];   // ... Copy it to the lastIndex place 

Array.Resize(ref Numbers, lastIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of C#, you can do something like this:

```
int[] x = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

x = x[..^1]; // this takes everything except the last position.

Console.WriteLine(x.Length); // 2
```